# Sata Connection HP Envy 14

Tags: sata, hp-envy

i have a hp ENVY 14 sleekbook beats audio and i cannot for the life of me figure out where the sata cable for a hard drive connects to the motherboard, can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Remember, just about every HP product has a publicly available service and maintenance manual... Just Google your model and "maintenance and service guide" or "technical manual" and you will almost always find the PDF in the top search results. They are complete technical breakdown manuals with disassembly, parts lists, etc. Invaluable resource, and one of the reasons I really like HP products... In this case: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02835360 would likely be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the service manual, it looks like this is connected underneath the system board. You'll need to remove it from the laptop entirely before you can get to the SATA connector.

[image: Hard disk drive adapter cable connection point]

[image: Hard disk drive adapter cable connection point 2]

Reference: http://h20574.www2.hp.com/results.htm?SID=5375376&MEID=925992DF-B026-495E-B859-68417615BF7D (Hard disk drive adapter cable guide)

Comment: Grateful for this

Comment: @user2293554 Glad to be of help! Remember to mark answers that help as accepted by click the green tick.